# A question about Lang's explanation of ordered fields on pg 449

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, and $P$ the set of positive elements. We know that $P$ is closed under addition and multiplication. It is also easily seen that $1\in P$. Assume that $x\in P$. Then $xx^{-1}=1$. Lang's Algebra says that as $x,1\in P$, this implies that $x^{-1}\in P$ also. I don't see why that is.

Comment: I don't have Lang handy, but in an ordered field, every non-zero element is either in $P$ or $-P$, and since $P$ is closed under multiplication, the product of a positive and negative element must be negative.  Now argue by contradiction.

Comment: Agree with @Aaron but there's also a notion of preordering that doesn't require $K$ to be the union of $P$ and $-P$.  It does however require $y^2 \in P$ for all $y \in K$, so that $x^{-2} \in P$.  Then $x^{-1} = x\cdot x^{-2}$ is also in $P$.

Comment: @Aaron- How would you argue that the product of a positive and a negative element need be negative? Remember that the only definition of a negative number that we have is a number that is not in P.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^{-1}\not\in P$, then $-x^{-1}\in P$. Hence $-1 = (-x^{-1})\cdot x \in P$, contradiction.